# What language would accomplish this?

Tags: web-applications

I would like to make a website that acts as a sort of game lobby. On some games, like Call of Duty, it can be hard to find other players, so instead of searching in the game, they can go online and see who else is online and playing and match up quickly.

The website will list some games and maybe some sub-categories for those games and show who else is online and looking for people. What language would I use to do this and where can I learn it? Can this, in any way, be done with PHP?

How does http://www.omgpop.com/ do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done in PHP, and I even think this is the preferred language, as it's cheap (free), powerful, and easy to learn.

You will need other languages to develop the games themselves in, though.

If you get really a lot of visitors, PHP might not suffice, but that's a worry for later.

Mind though, that developing a service like this is not an easy task. By the tone of your question, I feel you haven't got a whole lot of experience in this area (web development), so I'd figure out first if you're up to this task.

Comment: I'm not developing a game, just trying to make a website for people to group together.

Comment: How would this be done in PHP?

How does http://www.omgpop.com/ do it?

Comment: On the server you can create a list of users looking for opponents. This list is kept by PHP, and is stored in a Database or in MemCache. A memory based solution is the best, because it will have a lot of reading and writing. But it will be tough explaining the details in this 600 character comment. Especially since you apparently haven't even got a clou where to start. :)

Comment: I'm decent in PHP, I just don't know how to do anything like what you're talking about.

Comment: I thought databases were more for logging and user data, would they work like this, in real-time?

Comment: Depends on the number of users and the power of your server, but yes they can. If in doubt, MySQL has a special in-memory storage engine. Data in these tables is lost when the server goes down (as is data in MemCache). But that's usually no problem for this kind of data. Users will probably have to reconnect anyway if your server was to go down.

Comment: So you're saying all I have to do is use MySQL databases...

Comment: I'm saying you would probably benefit from gaining some experient by reading a book and doing a simpler project first. And yes, it can be done using MySQL, as long as you don't have tens of thousands of visitors.